# Need to find the bitrate of video stream but ffprobe exits earlier with error unsupported codec before reaching to video stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video, bitrate, hls, ffprobe

We are seeing an issue while finding the HLS videostream bit rate with ffprobe.
The stream has some timed metadata and when we run ffprobe with HLS input, error occurs: Unsupported codec with id 98313 for input stream 2
and ffprobe exits.
Is there a way that ffprobe can ignore the error and continue so that we can reach to the video bitrate?

ffmpeg works fine with the same HLS input.
eg:ffmpeg -re -i $1 -c copy -flush_packets 0 -f mpegts -pcr_period 20
-muxrate 5550k "udp://238.5.6.35:7408?pkt_size=1316&&bitrate=5550000&localaddr=192.168.0.35" -v debug

In this command instead of using hard coded bitrate, we want to get bitrate information using ffprobe from the input HLS stream, and would like to use that.

Logs from ffprobe:
ffprobe example.net/sample.m3u8
ffprobe version git-2023-07-31-d525312a Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.3.0 (crosstool-NG )
configuration: --cross-prefix=arm-linux- --arch=armel --target-os=linux --extra-cflags='-I/cird/users/master/comps/rs_tools/pkgs/openssl/openssl-1.0.2s/include -I/cird/users/master/comps/rs_tools/rel/2/target/lib -I/cird/users/master/comps/rs_tools/rel/2/target/bin' --extra-cxxflags='-I/cird/users/master/comps/rs_tools/pkgs/openssl/openssl-1.0.2s/include -I/cird/user/master/comps/rs_tools/rel/2/target/lib -I/cird/users/master/comps/rs_tools/rel/2/target/bin' --extra-ldflags=-L/cird/users/master/comps/rs_tools/rel/2/target/lib --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-openssl --prefix=/cird/users/master/comps/rel/2/target --disable-w32threads --disable-large-tests
libavutil      58. 14.100 / 58. 14.100
libavcodec     60. 22.100 / 60. 22.100
libavformat    60. 10.100 / 60. 10.100
libavdevice    60.  2.101 / 60.  2.101
libavfilter     9. 10.100 /  9. 10.100
libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
[hls @ 0x52560] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0x52560] Skip ('#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS')
[hls @ 0x52560] Opening 'example.net/encHLS/test2/sampleenc.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0x52560] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0x52560] Opening 'example.net/my.key' for reading
[hls @ 0x52560] Opening 'crypto+example.net/encHLS/test2/sampleenc-20231003T160408-_11450.ts' for reading
Input #0, hls, from 'example.net/encHLS/test2/sample.m3u8':
Duration: N/A, start: 34383.647000, bitrate: N/A
Program 0
Metadata:
variant_bitrate : 7248561
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn
Metadata:
variant_bitrate : 7248561
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Metadata:
variant_bitrate : 7248561
Stream #0:2: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
Metadata:
variant_bitrate : 7248561
Unsupported codec with id 98313 for input stream 2

Comment: Does it work with ffmpeg ? Please give more details about the input video.

Comment: Yes, works fine with ffmpeg. eg: ffmpeg -re -i $1  -c copy -flush_packets 0  -f mpegts -pcr_period 20 -muxrate 5550k "udp://238.5.6.35:7408?pkt_size=1316&&bitrate=5550000&localaddr=192.168.0.35" -v debug In this command instead of using hard coded bitrate, we want to get bitrate information using ffprobe and would like to use that.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1811073/edit) your question with the additional data. It's unreadable in comment format.

Comment: How many streams are present in the media?

Comment: 3 streams:  Stream #0:0, 37, 1/90000: Video: h264 (Main), 1 reference frame ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, left), 1920x1080 (1920x1088) [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 0/1, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 7248561
  Stream #0:1(eng), 1, 1/90000: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 7248561
  Stream #0:2, 0, 1/90000: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449), 0/1
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 7248561